# Why is the dwControlKeyState of the pressed key does not match constant?

Tags: c++, c, windows, keyboard

I'm trying to handle the keypress event of the console in Windows 7.
When I'm press a left ctrl key i'm expecting to get code 0x0008 (0b00001000 - LEFT_CTRL_PRESSED), but instead of this i'm getting 0x0028 (0b00101000).

```
...
DWORD n;
INPUT_RECORD ir;
HANDLE hin;
hin = GetStdHandler(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
...
ReadConsoleInput(hin, &ir, 1, &n)...
...
if(ir.Event.KeyEvent.dwControlKeyState == LEFT_CTRL_PRESSED) {
// some code..
}
```

if using **xor 32** all works fine:

```
if((ir.Event.KeyEvent.dwControlKeyState ^ 32) == LEFT_CTRL_PRESSED) {
// some code..
}
```

Where did the extra bits?

p.s.: project in unicode

Comment: The NumLock key is turned on, NUMLOCK_ON flag = 0x20.  Testing bits with the & operator is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dwControlKeyState` is a bitmap.

The single bits of the `dwControlKeyState` describe the states of certain keys at the same time.

The 3rd (0-indexed) bit equals 0x008 and  indicates left-ctrl-key pressed.

To test for it do like so:

```
if (ir.Event.KeyEvent.dwControlKeyState & LEFT_CTRL_PRESSED) {
// some code..
}
```

For a full description of this bitmap you might like to read here under `dwControlKeyState`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684166%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if `LEFT_CTRL_PRESSED` is active, you should use

```
if (ir.Event.KeyEvent.dwControlKeyState & LEFT_CTRL_PRESSED)
```

as `dwControlKeyState` contains several bits indicating different things. Your `^ 32` will invert the value of the `NUMLOCK_ON` bit, so if you press num-lock, your code will suddenly change behaviour - which is probably not what you want to do.